# How to (implicitly) pass environment variables to Maven build in gitlab-ci.yml for a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gitlab-ci

In a gitlab-ci.yml I'm building a Spring Boot app using Maven. To replace placeholder @MY_PROP@ in application.properties (using the Maven resources plugin) MY_PROP is passed as -D parameter to the mvn command.
Since there are a lot of parameters in my build, is there a way to pass environment varaibles to Maven without explicitly passing each individual env parameter via -D?

```
application.properties 
    my.prop=@MY_PROP@

gitlab env variable 
    MY_PROP=4711

gitlab-ci.yml
    Build:
        image: maven:3-jdk-11
        stage: build
        script:
            - mvn clean package deploy -s ci_settings.xml --batch-mode -DMY_PROP=$MY_PROP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Maven reference: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html

You can do:

> `env.*`
>
> Environment variables like `PATH` and `M2_HOME` can be referenced using the `env.*` prefix.

So in your pom.xml you can reference them as:

```
${env.MY_PROP}
```

In your case, to replace with resource plugin you can write:

```
my.prop=@env.MY_PROP@
```

Comment: Thanks, so in my case it is: my.prop=@env.MY_PROP@ If you include that in your answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: @cnmuc is it ok now?